# How do I use sort on multiple columns with different data types

Tags: sort, numeric-data

Here's my tab-delimited file t.tsv:

```
$ cat t.tsv
2022/05/05  -258.03
2022/05/07  -18.10
2022/05/09  -10.74
2022/05/09  -132.60
2022/05/12  -18.56
2022/05/12  -20.20
2022/05/17  -11.00
2022/05/17  -112.91
2022/05/17  -51.43
2022/05/17  -64.78
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -7.51
2022/05/19  -17.08
2022/05/20  -33.08
```

I am using MacOS 12.4 sort (from man page: *The sort utility is compliant with the IEEE Std 1003.1-2008 (“POSIX.1”) specification*) to sort first by col 1 in alpha seq ascending, then by col2 in numeric ascending.

```
$ cat t.tsv|sort --field-separator='\t' --key=1,1 --key=2,2n
2022/05/05  -258.03
2022/05/07  -18.10
2022/05/09  -10.74
2022/05/09  -132.60
2022/05/12  -18.56
2022/05/12  -20.20
2022/05/17  -11.00
2022/05/17  -112.91
2022/05/17  -51.43
2022/05/17  -64.78
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -7.51
2022/05/19  -17.08
2022/05/20  -33.08
```

I'm baffled as to why the second column is isn't being sorted in ascending *numeric* sequence when the first column is the same. Numerous SE answers to this same question all say that (a) you specify single columns as `--key=1,1`, and (b) you may apply options such as `-n` to individual key definitions like `--key=2,2n`.

**Update:** I should mention that my shell is `bash`.

Comment: You've misspelled it. To get ASCII characters, use double quotes (`--field-separator="\t"`), not single quotes (`--field-separator='\t' `). As you have it, `sort`-uses the two characters backslash and `t` for a column separator, and never sees a 2nd column.

Comment: I can reproduce this if I copy/paste the data and the tabs turn into spaces -- then sort is only seeing one field instead of two. Is it possible that your file is not actually tab-delimited?

Comment: You can see what the column separator is with `head -n4 t.tsv | od -bc`.

Comment: @waltinator is there a `sort` implementation that accepts two-character field separators? My GNU `sort` complains about `multi-character tab ‘\\t’` while my busybox sort complains about `bad -t parameter`. I don't have a BSD sort to test on, can you confirm that it would actually use a two-character field separator?

Comment: @waltinator `sort` on macOS would need a literal tab character, not ``\`` and `t`, as @terdon suspects.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Have verified the field delimiter is 0x09 == /t.

Comment: @waltinator Neither `-t "\t"` nor `--field-separator="\t"` solve the problem, although it's accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know of a `sort` implementation that understands `\t` or other such character representations, you need to use [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) instead:

```
sort --field-separator=$'\t' --key=1,1 --key=2,2n t.tsv
```

Also, according to [this macOS man page](https://ss64.com/osx/sort.html), "*The Apple man page for sort includes GNU long options for all the above, but these have not (yet) been implemented under macOS.*"   In recent releases of macOS, both `--key` and `--field-separator` are implemented for `sort`, but I would still use the standard short options for guaranteed portability:

```
sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1 -k 2,2n t.tsv
```

The above command, with macOS, GNU, and busybox `sort`, returns:

```
$ sort -t $'\t' -k 1,1 -k 2,2n t.tsv
2022/05/05  -258.03
2022/05/07  -18.10
2022/05/09  -132.60
2022/05/09  -10.74
2022/05/12  -20.20
2022/05/12  -18.56
2022/05/17  -112.91
2022/05/17  -64.78
2022/05/17  -51.43
2022/05/17  -11.00
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -13.96
2022/05/18  -7.51
2022/05/19  -17.08
2022/05/20  -33.08
```

Comment: The only special 2-character value that can be used with `-t` is `\0` which specifies that the field separator is the NUL character. This is not standard though but should work with GNU `sort` and with the `sort` implementation on macOS (and FreeBSD and OpenBSD).